# Retrieving page_fans using FQL from Insights table

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I m trying to retrieve the `page_fans` using the following FQL query ([Insights Table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/)).

```
SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=182929845081087 AND metric='page_fans' AND end_time=1334905200 AND period=86400
```

But I just get blank data , when I make the above query.

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

I m able to retrieve the other metrics by just changing the `metric` value in the above query.

For Eg. I get the `page_engaged_users` by just changing the `metric` value in the above query.

```
SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=182929845081087 AND metric='page_engaged_users' AND end_time=1334905200 AND period=86400

{
  "data": [
    {
      "metric": "page_engaged_users", 
      "value": 35
    }
  ]
}
```

What is wrong with the first query in which I m trying to retrieve the `page_fans` ??

And I know that I can retrieve page_fans using other ways as well !!

Comment: why not use the Graph api - graph.facebook.com/182929845081087?fields=likes ?

Comment: @bkvirendra, Could you please tell me other ways to retrieve page_fans. I know that Graph API is alternative way...but if possible can you give the relative path for the request...

I have tried to get the no of likes for my page on  a particular period or day using the URL "../id/page_fans?access_token=...", but I am not receiving any thing. Please suggest me if you know how to  do it with Graph API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the insights documentation, notice in the last column that the `page_fans` metric is only available for the lifetime `period`. Change your query to `period=0` or `period=period('lifetime') and you'll get data.

If you want the new fans added on a given day, use the `page_fan_adds` metric with `period('day')`.

If you request any other period, you will either get an error or no data (which means someone other than you *can* request that metric for a different period).

The other problem could be that you are requesting data that is too recent. In your query, you're looking at 2012-04-20, so you should be fine. When I tested this, I got no data if I used a date greater than 2012-09-15 (on 2012-09-18).